# Android - ListView not displaying in New Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

I'm fairly new to Android and object-oriented code, so I'm likely overlooking something small.

I have an `Activity` containing some custom `ListView`s that are in `Fragment`s, changed via swipe and tabs. Upon pressing a particular item in a particular list a few times, a new `Activity` should open and contain another `ListView`.

When I run my code, I can get the second Activity (`FactoryScreen.java`) to open from my Fragment (`StatusFragment.java`), however `FactoryScreen.java` appears as a blank `Activity`.

I've been trawling through forums online for similar cases but haven't had any luck. Again, since I'm new to this, I'm not entirely sure of ways to debug this. I have noticed, however, that `fragment_factory_screen.xml`, which contains the Activity layout, is entirely fine with displaying a `TextView` item (with basic "Hello world"), but apparently not a `ListView`.

StatusFragment.java (FactoryScreen.java initialised from here via an Intent)

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import com.example.path.R;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class StatusFragment extends Fragment
    {
         private Context mContext;
         private ArrayList<DataItem> data = new ArrayList<DataItem>(); // DataItem contains two strings
         ListView myList;
         int i = 0;

         @Override
         public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {    
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

              mContext = getActivity(); // Get the context of the Activity and therefore the fragment
              myList = new ListView (mContext); // Create a ListView

              // Fill out elements to go into 'data'
              ...
              // data.add each DataItem variable
              ...
          }

          @Override
          public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
          {
               // Inflate the view
               View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, container, false);

               // (?) Identify myList to be a list to be placed in rootView
               myList=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
               // Create and set the customised adapter to take data (ArrayList<DataItem>) and format
               // each element placed as defined in list_row.xml
               CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(mContext, R.layout.list_row, data);
               myList.setAdapter(adapter);

               // When a myList item is clicked, show a Toast.
               myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
               {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position, long id)
                    {
                         // If Item 1 is clicked 3 times, open new Activity
                     if(id == 1)
                     {
                          i++;
                          if(i == 3)
                          {
                               Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FactoryScreen.class);
                           i = 0;
                           startActivity(intent);    
                          }
                          else
                          {
                                   ...
                          }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          ...
                     }
                     }
                 });
             return rootView; // onCreateView must return a View variable if displaying a UI.
         }
     }
```

FactoryScreen.java (Activity to be opened, ListView doesn't display)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.baseappwithcalibration.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FactoryScreen extends Activity {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<DataItem> data = new ArrayList<DataItem>();
    ListView myList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_factory_screen);

        mContext = this; // Get the context of the Activity and therefore the fragment
        myList = new ListView (mContext); // Create a ListView

        // Create elements to be added to the list
        ...

        // Add elements to the list
        ...
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the view
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_factory_screen, container, false);

        // (?) Identify myList to be a list to be placed in rootView
        myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        // Create and set the customised adapter to take data (ArrayList<DataItem>) and format
        // each element as defined in list_row.xml
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(mContext, R.layout.list_row, data);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // When a myList item is clicked, show a Toast.
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                // This is used in the form of Toast.makeText(Context, Text, Duration);
                Toast.makeText(FactoryScreen.this, "This is the description of the parameter.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return rootView; // onCreateView must return a View variable if displaying a UI.
    }
}
```

fragment_factory_screen.xml (Contains layout for FactoryScreen.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    </ListView> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help/guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method called `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` for an activity.Thus is function will not be executed in your case.This is why the `ListView` is not visible. So in the FactoryScreen Activity,move code from this method `onCreateView()` to `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_factory_screen);

    mContext = this; // Get the context of the Activity and therefore the fragment

    // (?) Identify myList to be a list to be placed in rootView
    myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    // Create and set the customised adapter to take data (ArrayList<DataItem>) and format
    // each element as defined in list_row.xml
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(mContext, R.layout.list_row, data);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // When a myList item is clicked, show a Toast.
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            // This is used in the form of Toast.makeText(Context, Text, Duration);
            Toast.makeText(FactoryScreen.this, "This is the description of the parameter.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: It works - thanks! I had tried something like this previously but I had issues with the View scoping. Strangely enough they haven't reappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In your FactoryScreen, in your `onCreate` method

```
myList = new ListView (mContext); // Create a ListView
```

You don't add the listView in your layout.

If the layout R.layout.fragment_factory_screen contains the ListView, you can retrieve it with

```
myList=(ListView)findViewById(myId);
```

otherwise you have to add to your view with code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've resolved it now, I tried something like this earlier but had no luck. I've figured that the approach may not have worked the first time because I was trying to create the list before I had added the elements to it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

in **`onCreateView()`**

```
myList=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```